# labels in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textarea

```
<input name="textbox" type="text" value="Click here to type" onfocus="if(this.value=='Click here to type')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Click here to type';">
```

..onfocus/onblur work on textfields but not textarea elements. Is there any workaround, using jQuery maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<textarea onfocus="if(this.value=='Click here to type')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Click here to type';">Click here to type</textarea>
```

Works for me.

Could fail if you put some extra newlines/spaces in the value of course.

Answer (score 3):

The `onfocus` and `onblur` events work on all form elements and anchors, you can try just making your `input` a `textarea`, and it will work, but I would encourage you to do your event binding programmatically.

Something like this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textareaId'),
    message = 'Click here to type';

textarea.value = message; // set default value

textarea.onfocus = textarea.onblur = function () {

  if (this.value == '') {
    this.value = message;
  } else if (this.value == message) {
    this.value = '';
  }
};
```

Try the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/uxuma).

jQuery [version](http://jsbin.com/avotu):

```
$(function () { 
  var message = 'Click here to type'; 

  $('#textareaId').val(message); // set default value 

  $('#textareaId').bind('focus blur', function () { 
    var $el = $(this); 
    if ($el.val() == '') { 
      $el.val(message); 
    } else if ($el.val() == message) { 
      $el.val(''); 
    } 
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Watermark plugin for jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/).

> This simple-to-use jQuery plugin adds
>   watermark capability to HTML input and
>   textarea elements.
>
> This plugin lets you specify the text
>   that will be used for the watermark,
>   and optionally you can supply your own
>   CSS class name that will be applied to
>   the input or textarea element every
>   time the watermark is shown.
>
> If you do not supply your own class
>   name, the class name "watermark" is
>   used.
>
> In addition, this plugin allows you to
>   change the watermark text and/or class
>   name any time after the watermark is
>   initialized.
>
> The plugin is also capable of
>   displaying a watermark in password
>   input elements, showing the watermark
>   in plain text, but then switching to
>   password-protected (obscured) mode
>   when focused. (Because of the
>   complexity of making password
>   watermarks operate, it is recommended
>   that programmatic changes to password
>   input elements be avoided.)
>
> New for version 3.0, the plugin can
>   also handle input elements of
>   type="search" (WebKit browsers), and
>   it supports drag-and-drop to
>   watermarked elements, plug native
>   browser support (when available).